# How do we dynamically change the assembly path in DLLImport attribute?

Tags: c#, c++

How do we change the assembly path in DLLImport attribute inside an if conditional statement?
e.g. I want to do something like this:

```
string serverName = GetServerName();
if (serverName == "LIVE")
{
   DLLImportString = "ABC.dll";

}
else
{
DLLImportString = "EFG.dll";
}

DllImport[DLLImportString]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't set attribute's value wich is calculated during runtime

You can define two methods with diff `DllImports` and call them in your if statement

```
DllImport["ABC.dll"]
public static extern void CallABCMethod();

DllImport["EFG.dll"]
public static extern void CallEFGMethod();

string serverName = GetServerName(); 
if (serverName == "LIVE") 
{ 
   CallABCMethod();
} 
else 
{ 
   CallEFGMethod();
}
```

Or you can try to Load dll dynamicaly with winapi LoadLibrary

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary")]
static extern int LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpLibFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress")]
static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress( int hModule,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpProcName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary")]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(int hModule);
```

Create delegate that fits method in dll

```
delegate void CallMethod();
```

And then try to use something like that

```
   int hModule = LoadLibrary(path_to_your_dll);  // you can build it dynamically
   if (hModule == 0) return;
   IntPtr intPtr = GetProcAddress(hModule, method_name);
   CallMethod action = (CallMethod)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(intPtr, typeof(CallMethod));
   action.Invoke();
```

Comment: The path is retrieved the DB and it will change many times during the project's lifetime.  I don't want to change the code everytime

Answer (score 4):

You need to manually load the dll via LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress.

I had the same need for a small application and used c++/cli.

In c# it will look something like:

```
delegate int MyFunc(int arg1, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String arg2);

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    IntPtr mydll = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
    IntPtr procaddr = GetProcAddress(mydll, "Somfunction");
    MyFunc myfunc = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procaddr, typeof(MyFunc));
    myfunc(1, "txt");
}
```

Edit: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/07/14/181932.aspx) is complete example

Answer (score 1):

May be you could differentiate your builds using conditional compilation?
If you can [/define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that a build is for server A, eg. compiling with /define serverA, then you could have

```
#if serverA
DllImport["ABC.dll"]
#else
DllImport["EFG.dll"]
#endif
```

[More #if info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)